# Viewport glitch while retopoing

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I am using Blender 2.81 on Windows 10, and twice have I run into the glitch shown in the image below. Both times I was in the middle of retopologizing this head sculpt (gray). I can't pinpoint the exact actions I had taken the first time I ran into it. The second time happened when I jumped from edit mode into object mode.

This happened on the default "Sculpting" tab.

1. Moving along the viewport disabling models, etc. did not eliminate the glitch.
2. Same for switching between Object, Edit and Sculpting modes.
3. Weirdly enough, switching to other tabs, such as "Layout", did.

This did not affect other windows. This includes videos that were 
playing on Firefox, as well as the Paint window I used to screencap and crop the accompanying image.

Is this a glitch in Blender, or is my graphics card dying?

[image: Viewport glitch]

Thank you!

EDIT: Since I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question, I'll leave this as an edit.

After fiddling around with the file, I found out it has to do with the "In front" display for the retopo mesh (blue). Disabling it makes the glitch go away, and enabling it makes it come back.

Finding this out enabled me to find [a similar bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T67615) for 2.80. Since the OP had a similar graphics card to mine (both Radeon 5X0s), I assume it has something to do with AMD cards. Apparently this issue has been fixed in 2.82.

Comment: Hello :). Just wanted to say thanks for digging through bug reports and letting us know about the reason. I'm sure it'll be helpful to someone.

Comment: No worries! The Blender community does so much for us, it's only fair I can do a little bit for it.